# sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlsrv

I get a error --> *sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource* 
Can anyone figure out whats wrong with the coding, ive been trying for 3 hours now
Thanks in advance :)

```
<?php
include("config.php");

 username and password sent from form 
 $myusername=htmlspecialchars($_POST[username]); 
 $mypassword=htmlspecialchars($_POST[password]); 



 $sql="SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username=$myusername and 
  Password=$mypassword";
  $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
  $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

  if($count==1){
     header("location: something");
  }
 else {
     echo "Wrong Username or Password";



 } 
 ?>
```

## CONFIG.PHP

```
 <?php
   $serverName = ''; 
   $uid = '';   
   $pwd = '';  
   $databaseName = ''; 
   $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                     "Database"=>$databaseName); 

   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
      if( $conn ) {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
       }else{
              echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: `$result` is probably false, meaning your query failed, which seems likely if that's actually your SQL query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSRV\_NUM\_ROWS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858327/sqlsrv-num-rows-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

The issue is `$result` is false and it is because of:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username=$myusername and 
  Password=$mypassword";
```

here `Username` and `Password` are strings and you to compare with string you have to wrap the values in `'` singe quotes like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username='".$myusername."' and 
  Password='".$mypassword."'";
```

**Note: Your query is vulnerable to sql injections**

Comment: OMG THANKS! What could i do to prevent sql injections?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202006/prevention-of-sql-injection-with-php-for-sql-server-and-without-pdo

Answer (score 0):

I have notice 2 things here:

1) You have a typo at line 4, I think you missed the comment markup

instead of:

```
username and password sent from form
```

you mean:

```
// username and password sent from form
```

2) Mayank already anwsered that second issue. You have another typo at SQL Query and the $result variable is returning FALSE instead of a statement resource

You could verify that checking if $result is equal to FALSE, and furthermore print some error for the user, like this:

```
if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-query.php) for more information.

**Finally mind what Mayank said about SQL injection.**